# Re. Search inside MenuBar WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

I am trying to put my `woocommerce product search widget` inside the Menu. Can someone show me the right way of doing this.

here is my code 1st

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
register_sidebar(array(
  'id' => 'search-widget',
  'name' => __('Search Widget'),
  'description' => __('Drag search widget to this container'),
  'before_widget' => '<article id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
  'after_widget' => '</article>',
  'before_title' => '<h6>',
  'after_title' => '</h6>'      
  ));
}
```

then I want to put this widget inside the Menubar.

```
    function include_search_box($items, $args) {
        // only display search box on our primary menu
        if( 'primary' === $args -> theme_location )
    $items .= '<li dynamic_sidebar("search-widget")>' . '</li>';
    return $items;
    }
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'include_search_box', 10, 2 );
```

My problem is the `search Box` doesn't appear. How can i insert the widget with my current menu where in it will not affect all the items inside My Menu.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a screen shot or jsfiddle of what you want to happen?

Comment: nothing happen the search box didnt appear